# DB2 v10 database size growth monitoring range

Tags: db2

I need to know my IBM DB2 database growth range. e.g. database size growth from last 1 month or last 3 months or Last 6 months ..
Please assist or anyone can provide query or else advice accordingly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what the question is. Are you asking: How do I find the growth of my IBM DB2 Database over the last month, or last 3 months? If you could edit your question to be a bit clearer, it may help others understand so they can better assist you.

Comment: i would like to know the database size growth trend, (e.g. whats the size of DB before 6 months or before 3 months), so that one can know the db size growth trend approximately.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Data Server Manager (DSM) has this capability if you use it with a repository database.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042233

It won't be able to provide this information for dates before you install and setup DSM, but it will going forward.